# Without SSL Certificate location is not detecting in Chrome

Tags: javascript, ssl, https

We did notice today an issue in automatic detection of zip code based on the user s location. I is not working in Chrome but when i open the url in Chrome it didn't work. We had to configure the sites to https and then it works ok.

Example : https://where-am-i.live works well with SSL certificate but without https it is not working in Chrome.

Comment: and what exactly is the question here?

Comment: "As of Chrome 50, the Geolocation API will only work on secure contexts such as HTTPS. If your site is hosted on an non-secure origin (such as HTTP) the requests to get the users location will no longer function." https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_geolocation.asp

Answer (score 0):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Geolocation_API

> This feature is available only in secure contexts (HTTPS), in some or
>   all supporting browsers.